# Windows 8 Local DataBase (Capture and store images) C#

Tags: database, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am making a Windows 8 application where user will capture images and save it in local database.

After doing a lot of search regarding "DataBase on windows 8" Still I am not sure what Database will best for such application that captures and store images with some "details".

I read that SQLlite creates problem while submitting apps to Windows 8 app store,

Is there any option other than writing to text files or using JSON?

Please guide me. ( also please let me know if any one knows about a sample app I can take help)

Thanks 
Zauk

Comment: What problems regarding SQLite and Store apps.  I know there are sometimes arcane messages regarding what you need to have in terms of the SQLlite DLLs for various platforms, but those are solvable AFAIK.

Comment: Hi Jim O'Neil
My development machine is running/compiling my application only for x64 and x86 CPUs but given errors when I select ARM,So  What should I do for ARM devices(like windows surface) ?

Comment: Tim Heuer has some [pretty extensive blog posts on using SQLite with Windows 8](http://timheuer.com/blog/tags/sqlite/default.aspx), I would review those and then post specific questions/errors in a new SO thread.

Answer (score 0):

i wish i can use localDB in my Win 8 app :/ but you can build SQLite from source ->
[take a look here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/20/using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx)

good luck

Comment: Yes I did same , One thing I wanna ask, when ever I run my project I need to specify any CPU, why its not running with option "any CPU"? and let suppose I run it with x64 CPU and submit to appstore then users with x86 or ARM CPU's can install and use my application? or it will only for x64 CPU?

Comment: .NET is a just-in-time compiled language.  When you compile you compile to MSIL which is than recompiled to x86, x64, or ARM at run-time.  SQLLite is natively compiled to start with, so you need to have the specific x86, x64, or ARM binaries to compile your app with.  This means, for Windows Store, you have to submit three versions of your app instead of one.  Microsoft has instructions on how to do this -- it will look the same to your users, but they will get the right version for their platform when they download it.

Comment: Thanks Bytemaster, please also guide me about one thing, My development machine is running/compiling my application only for x64 and x86 CPUs but given errors when I select ARM, What should I do?Can you suggest any other database for C# that will not do any problem like this?
Thanks again.